# Push multiple array fields into separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a requirement where I have data in this format. How can I or What is the best and easiest to get the output in the below format?

```
users = [
{
id: "1",
name: "Norah"
},
{
id: "2",
name: "Alyx"
}
];
accounts = [
{
account: "IRA-4679",
user: "1",
balance: "5175.36"
},
{
account: "AAA-3571",
user: "1",
balance: "3106701.85"
},
{
account: "AAA-4671",
user: "1",
balance: "138971.19"
},
{
account: "ROT-1687",
user: "2",
balance: "2686.00"
},
{
account: "AAA-7894",
user: "2",
balance: "68761.32"
},
{
account: "IRA-6818",
user: "2",
balance: "564.67"
},
{
account: "IRA-6819",
user: "2",
balance: "6564.67"
}
];
```

Output

```
["Norah | AAA-6818 | 564.67","Norah | AAA-4671 | 138971.19"]
```

Is it something related to splitting array and merging into one based on id or what should I do it here?

Comment: Your output is incorrect, can you update it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users=[{id:"1",name:"Norah"},{id:"2",name:"Alyx"}];
const accounts=[{account:"IRA-4679",user:"1",balance:"5175.36"},{account:"AAA-3571",user:"1",balance:"3106701.85"},{account:"AAA-4671",user:"1",balance:"138971.19"},{account:"ROT-1687",user:"2",balance:"2686.00"},{account:"AAA-7894",user:"2",balance:"68761.32"},{account:"IRA-6818",user:"2",balance:"564.67"},{account:"IRA-6819",user:"2",balance:"6564.67"}];

const res = accounts.map(e => [
  users.find(x => x.id === e.user).name,
  e.account,
  e.balance
].join(" | "))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: how can I apply sorting in output based on name or account balance?

Answer (score 0):

```js
users = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Norah",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Alyx",
  },
];

accounts = [
  {
    account: "IRA-4679",
    user: "1",
    balance: "5175.36",
  },
  {
    account: "AAA-3571",
    user: "1",
    balance: "3106701.85",
  },
  {
    account: "AAA-4671",
    user: "1",
    balance: "138971.19",
  },
  {
    account: "ROT-1687",
    user: "2",
    balance: "2686.00",
  },
  {
    account: "AAA-7894",
    user: "2",
    balance: "68761.32",
  },
  {
    account: "IRA-6818",
    user: "2",
    balance: "564.67",
  },
  {
    account: "IRA-6819",
    user: "2",
    balance: "6564.67",
  },
];

let finalOutput = users
  .sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))
  .map((user) =>
    accounts
      .filter((account) => account.user == user.id)
      .sort((a, b) => (parseFloat(a.balance) > parseFloat(b.balance) ? -1 : 1))
      .map(
        (filteredAccount) =>
          user.name +
          " | " +
          filteredAccount.account +
          " | " +
          filteredAccount.balance
      )
  );

console.log(finalOutput);
```

This should do the trick, for me running the above snippet turns your two inputs into an array of two arrays with the shape of this:

`["Alyx | AAA-7894 | 68761.32", "Alyx | IRA-6819 | 6564.67", "Alyx | ROT-1687 | 2686.00", "Alyx | IRA-6818 | 564.67"]`

and

`["Norah | AAA-3571 | 3106701.85", "Norah | AAA-4671 | 138971.19", "Norah | IRA-4679 | 5175.36"]`

EDIT: As requested I have now added sorting to first sort by name and then sort by account balance in descending order from largest to smallest.

Resulting in the updated outputs seen above.

Comment: how can I apply sorting in output based on name or account balance?

Comment: @KunalVijan I have now added sorting to sort first by user's name and then after that by their account balances in DESC order from largest account balance to smallest. If you wish to reverse this simply change the second sort function following the filter operation to be this instead `.sort((a, b) => (parseFloat(a.balance) > parseFloat(b.balance) ? 1 : -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the users, then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the accounts and use
[destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to return your string.

```js
const
  users = [{ id: "1", name: "Norah" }, { id: "2", name: "Alyx" }],
  accounts = [{ account: "IRA-4679", user: "1", balance: "5175.36" }, { account: "AAA-3571", user: "1", balance: "3106701.85" }, { account: "AAA-4671", user: "1", balance: "138971.19" }, { account: "ROT-1687", user: "2", balance: "2686.00" }, { account: "AAA-7894", user: "2", balance: "68761.32" }, { account: "IRA-6818", user: "2", balance: "564.67" }, { account: "IRA-6819", user: "2", balance: "6564.67" }],

  userMap = new Map(users.map(({ id, name }) => [id, name])),
  result = accounts.map(({ user, account, balance }) =>
    `${userMap.get(user)} | ${account} | ${balance}`);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you need to maintain the ability to access individual properties of user/account elements it will be better to keep them as objects. You can merge the user name into the accounts array and define a `toString()` function to easily convert either a single userAccount object to a string, or to map the entire array to strings as needed.

```js
const
  users = [{ id: "1", name: "Norah" }, { id: "2", name: "Alyx" }],
  accounts = [{ account: "IRA-4679", user: "1", balance: "5175.36" }, { account: "AAA-3571", user: "1", balance: "3106701.85" }, { account: "AAA-4671", user: "1", balance: "138971.19" }, { account: "ROT-1687", user: "2", balance: "2686.00" }, { account: "AAA-7894", user: "2", balance: "68761.32" }, { account: "IRA-6818", user: "2", balance: "564.67" }, { account: "IRA-6819", user: "2", balance: "6564.67" }],

  userAccountToString = (acct) => `${acct.user} | ${acct.account} | ${acct.balance}`,
  userMap = new Map(users.map(({ id, name }) => [id, name])),
  userAccounts = accounts.map(({ user, ...account }) =>
    ({ user: userMap.get(user), ...account }));

// accounts with user name merged
console.log(userAccounts);
console.log(userAccounts.map(userAccountToString));

// sort as needed
console.log('\nBy balance:')
userAccounts.sort((a, b) => a.balance - b.balance);
console.log(userAccounts);
// output array as account strings
console.log(userAccounts.map(userAccountToString));

// sort as needed
console.log('\nBy user:')
userAccounts.sort((a, b) => a.user.localeCompare(b.user));
console.log(userAccounts);
// output array as account strings
console.log(userAccounts.map(userAccountToString));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how can I apply sorting in output based on name or account balance?

Comment: If you want to maintain access to individual props like that you are better off keeping them as objects and defining a `toString()` method that outputs your desired string when you need it.